# Ternary in-line statement not working for third conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an in-line if-else statement for a  but it doesn't seem to recognise the third statement?

Also, if I take away the 4th "else" (the blank part), I get an error. The error is

`Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":"`

The starting state is "middle". So, the background should be "blue", but it is turning red for some reason. I have figured out that if I make "middle" the first if-else statement, it registers.

Is there any reason why my code would not be working?

Current State

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      theme: "middle",
    };
  }
```

Code in question

```
<div
          class="tweet"
          id="tweetHere"
          style={{
            background:
              props.selectedTheme === "light"
                ? "#fff"
                : "dark"
                ? "red"
                : "middle"
                ? "blue"
                : "",
          }}
        >
```

Comment: Hey, you got the ternary statement wrong

Comment: Sorry! could you point out where I went wrong?

Comment: a ternary statement can either return True or False so that means that it would only either say #fff or dark

Comment: So, do you want to say like if `prop.selectedTheme` is light. it should say #fff, red and blue?

Comment: Yes, but it can contain Conditional chains, which is why it is formatted like if x, else if x, else if x

Comment: @SrishruthikAlle I want if its light, do #fff, if dark, do red, if middle, do blue

Comment: When you check for anything other than "light" you will always get "red". Just putting "middle" isn't doing anything because it isn't a conditional check and will ALWAYS be true as it isn't falsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary statement is incorrect. Try below.

```
<div
  class="tweet"
  id="tweetHere"
  style={{
    background:
      props.selectedTheme === 'light'
        ? '#fff'
        : props.selectedTheme === 'dark'
        ? 'red'
        : props.selectedTheme === 'middle'
        ? 'blue'
        : ''
  }}
></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding about ternary is quite off.

```js
// for simplicity, let’s assign the value to a "t" variable. 
const t = props.selectedTheme;

const background = t == "light" ? "#fff" :
  t == "dark" ? "red" :
  t == "middle" ? "blue" : "";
```

You need to repeat the `==` check expression before each `?` it’s more like if-else, not switch-case.